# How to get parent group content from svg using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to get the content of `<g>` tag .
I have tried getElementsByTagName('g') but it returns all `<g>` in an array , I want just content of outer `<g>` .

Here is my svg

---

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" style="enable-background:new 0 0 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{font-family:'MyriadPro-Regular';}
 .st1{font-size:117.1799px;}
 .st2{fill:#17519D;}
 .st3{fill:#E1232E;}
 .st4{fill:#FAFDF9;}
</style>
<g>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 161.3171 175.1665)" class="st0 st1">text</text>
 <g id="xe_o3c0">
  <g id="xe_6ipa">
   <g id="xe_zj3t">
    <path id="xe_ce0v" pointer-events="bounding-box" class="st2" d=".4l1."/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 
<image style="overflow:visible;" width="728" height="625" xlink:href="http://magento1924.inkxe.com//xetool/assets/magento1924_inkxe_com/images/designs/16.jpg" transform="matrix(0.3073 0 0 0.3073 35.3171 216.8965)">
 </image>
</g>
</svg>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `id` as the selector?

```
getElementsById('xe_6ipa')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first group element in the SVG, you can use:

```
getElementsByTagName('g').item(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('g')` will return the first outer instance that it finds, and returns the node instead of a NodeList.